# Using external style sheet to style all instances of .net textboxes on a page

Tags: css, webforms

I have some textboxes I want to style and in design view, everything looks good. When I debug though, the CSS hasn't applied.

CSS:

```
input.textbox {
color: #C0C0C0;
text-align: center;
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" MaxLength="50" Text="First Name"></asp:TextBox>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why this wouldn't work, assuming your stylesheet is being included correctly and you've also ensured that `class="textbox"` is being added to the `input` elements. You should check to make sure your CSS is being included & the HTML is being generated correctly (check the network/elements pane of your browsers developer tool).

You could do this if you genuinely want to style every text input, and you wont need to add a `CssClass`.

```
input[type="text"]{
    color: #C0C0C0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. It now works in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE. All browsers are the most current versions. I'm assuming there is some added code to deal with IE needed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using IE 10.